# layer-list background not working for horizontal ProgressBar on Android Lollipop (5.1.1 / API 22)

Tags: android, xml

This is my layout XML for my **ProgressBar**:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/myProgressBar"

    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/my_progress_bar_height"
    android:maxHeight="@dimen/my_progress_bar_height"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/my_progress_bar"
    android:indeterminate="false"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imageViewSend"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/imageViewSend"
    android:max="10"
    android:progress="0"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

And here is the `progressDrawable` resource, **my_progress_bar.xml**, which should show a pair of lines for the ProgressBar (using four different colours in order to demonstrate the problem):

```
<item android:id="@android:id/background">

    <layer-list>
        <item android:gravity="top">
            <shape>
                <size android:height="@dimen/my_progress_bar_line_width" />
                <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:gravity="bottom">
            <shape>
                <size android:height="@dimen/my_progress_bar_line_width" />
                <solid android:color="@color/green" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>

</item>

<item
    android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <layer-list>
            <item android:gravity="top">
                <shape>
                    <size android:height="@dimen/my_progress_bar_line_width" />
                    <solid android:color="@color/yellow" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:gravity="bottom">
                <shape>
                    <size android:height="@dimen/my_progress_bar_line_width" />
                    <solid android:color="@color/red" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </clip>
</item>
```

On an Android Nougat (7.0 / API 24), the ProgressBar looks as intended:

[image: ProgressBar on Android Nougat device]

But on an Android Lollipop (5.1.1 / API 22), it looks like this:

[image: ProgressBar on Android Lollipop device]

...i.e., it seems like the widths I specify for the lines are not being respected.

Why is it displaying differently on the Android Lollipop device? And how to make it appear like it does for the Android Nougat device?

([This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36194746/1617737) to a similar question didn't help.)

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution, but it's not ideal as it means having separate background and progress drawable resources...

So I now have these two attributes for my **ProgressBar**:

```
<item name="android:background">@drawable/my_progress_bar_bg</item>
<item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/my_progress_bar_progress</item>
```

**my_progress_bar_bg.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid
                android:color="@color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:color="@color/progress_bg"
                android:width="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**my_progress_bar_progress.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <layer-list>
                <item
                    android:left="-2dp"
                    android:right="-2dp">
                    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                        <solid
                            android:color="@color/transparent" />
                        <stroke
                            android:color="@color/progress_progress"
                            android:width="2dp" />
                    </shape>
                </item>
            </layer-list>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```